# Solving equations from a logic puzzle about sumproduct

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

I have a question that I tried to solve, and I think I partially did it. Now I want to know if I did everything correctly and, if yes, is there any proof regarding this?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150193/discussion-on-question-by-h-h-solving-equations-using-sum-product-twice-with-un); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the function $f$ allows for arrays with non-integer elements, computing $a$ along with $c_1 = (1,...,1)$ and $c_2 = (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5},...)$ should work.

To get to another solution $b$ that satisfies $f(a,c_1) = f(b,c_1)$ and $f(a,c_2) = f(b,c_2)$, we can start with $a$ then repeatedly subtract $1$ from one component and add $1$ to another component. But all of the pairwise differences in $c_2$ are "linearly independent" up to integer scalar multiples, so any sequence of these moves would necessarily change $f(b, c_2)$.

Comment: But why can't we use only $ c_2$ then? We can then solve it by putting different linear combinations with integers and solve the equation eventually.
We will have sth like $A[1]*\sqrt(2) +A[2]*\sqrt3) ...  $. the number that this yields is unique right?

Comment: Great point. I think you are correct. Maybe the intended answer of two uses does not allow for the use of irrationals.

Comment: My main issue with this approach, is that given the computing-based-phrasing of the problem, you run into approximation errors. IE Like you said,  can we allow for non-integer elements?

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't think so, if yes the answer would be 1 not 2 times.